# Design patterns : How edit multiple entities from within a gateway

Tags: php, design-patterns, entity, gateway

We are now in a situation on a project that we need manipulate multiple user entities at once. By example we will disable 50 users at once. Normally we did that in a gateway

Gateway

- Query the data at once by the gateway with a query

OR

- Loop through multiple users

  - Load entity
  - Manipulate data
  - validate
  - save()

But that is not the best practice solution.

The first option overrule the possibility to validate the data.
The second is not good performing, because we need iterate the entity for all users

What do you suggest? We want a fast solution, but also a save solution

Hope someone know the right solution. Thanks!

When we use the

Answer (score 0):

You need an Object Realational Mapper (ORM) that has the feature to load those multiple users that match the loop at once so the load is reduced.

Similar for the save operation at the end. All changed entities should be stored at once with a unit of work.

Check the product documentation of the ORM you're using or contact it's vendor to find out which features it offers to support your development.

Comment: The difference is that we use a custom solution for Zend_Db. Because Zend_Db is to heavy. We did make a own one. But now we are on the case that we need to manage multiple entities. Normally we had the workaround to handle it in a gateway. But this is not the implementation what we want. IT is not for nothing a gateway. But for that we need find the right design pattern. Because we don't use the ORM anymore so as it aspects to be

Comment: The PofEAA book (http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/) has longer chapters about database related patterns covering problems like yours. I would invest the time to look into there, because it shows nicely the different approaches to these problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the first option. Updating them all at once in a single query. But you don't state what kind of data validation you would like to do. Maybe you could start a database transaction and issue a second query to validate the result of your 'user disable query' before committing?

Comment: Disabling users is one option. But when we want do more, like update information in other tables. Where user put data in. We need to know for sure that they not can place wrong input. In the entity all fields have validation, what can be empty, how long can a field be. What kind of datatype. Bij example if you have a number of 40integers. We need to know that it is a integer. That did the entity. A gateway have not that power

Comment: Maybe you could add a service layer. You call the service layer from your controller. You start the database transaction from the service and then call different table gateways. When all the gateway calls succeed you commit the transaction in the service.

Comment: I will look if this is the right solution. Sounds good. Hope it fits in our API on the right way. Thanks for your answer. I am always searching for more good options :-)